# utf-8 decoding problem in php

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, decode

I got a .vcf file with parts encoded as UTF-8:

```
CATEGORIES;CHARSET=UTF-8:StraÃŸe & â€“dienste
```

Now "`â€“`" should be a "`-`" and "`StraÃŸe`" should convert to "`Straße`".

I tried

- `utf8_decode()`
- `iconv()`
- `mb_convert_encoding()`

And have been playing with several output encoding options like

- `header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`
- `mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );`

But I don't get the wanted results - instead: "`StraÃ?e & â??dienste`"

Anyone getting that knot out of my brain? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**solved.**

i had to convert the PHP file back to ISO-8859-1 (instead of UTF-8).

thought that would make no difference, but it does!

Comment: Did you try to utf8_encode() the input, as PHP reads it in assuming it is not, and thus utf8_decode() on unencoded input is useless.

Comment: I haven't had much luck working with text editors that truly support UTF-8 editing.  They will typically take whatever codepage the OS is using (ISO-8859-1 = default for US/Western Europe).

Answer (score 0):

You may actually want to try utf8_encode(). I had a similar problem when retrieving UTF-8 encoded information from MySQL and displaying it on a UTF-8 HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to mention: there is no MySQL...

plain php ;-)

`echo "StraÃŸe & â€“dienste";`

`echo utf8_decode("StraÃŸe & â€“dienste");`

should somehow become "Straße & -dienste"... but won't, won't, won't

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you, as I'm not sure I understand fully what you are trying to do (read a .vcf file in PHP?)....

But a clue is this: "StraÃŸe" is "Straße" encoded in UTF-8, but then interpreted as Latin1 (or Windows-1252).